# What sorting algorithm does dplyr's arrange() use?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

Mostly a curiosity, I wanted to know what sorting algorithm dplyr's arrange function uses. I read that the most common sorting algorithm using R was selection sort, but I couldn't find any specifics about arrange(). I just have a bit of an interest in sorting algorithms and was curious which this function uses!

I looked at the source code for the arrange function, but I couldn't really tell which sorting method the function used. I'm new to R though, so it might be obvious, but I couldn't tell. I saw another post on stackoverflow that asked this, but unfortunately there was no clear answers on what sorting algorithm it uses :) Thank you!

Comment: Currently it uses `vctrs::vec_order_radix` internally which, based on the name, I’d assume performs radix sort. More details here: https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/blob/8bbd8c4a69a9b3e2c42aa752c5339f949562af96/R/order.R

Comment: @KonradRudolph ultimately that function calls the C function `vec_order` from the vctrs package, which uses an insertion sort for small vectors and a radix sort for larger vectors, as spelled out in the extended comments [here](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/blob/8bbd8c4a69a9b3e2c42aa752c5339f949562af96/src/order.c#L34)

Comment: @AllanCameron you've gone deep enough you should post as an answer

Comment: For future reference, you can download the full source code for any package at CRAN.

Comment: @GregorThomas OK, I've tried to post a fuller answer. There's quite a lot of redirection within the C code too (the `order.c` file is thousands of lines long), so I stopped before actually finding the specific C implementation of the sorting algorithm. I think I'll take the author's code comments at face value...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dplyr::arrange` is an S3 generic function, which only has a method defined for data frames (or objects that `inherit` class `"data.frame"`, such as tibbles). If we look at the code for `dplyr:::arrange.data.frame`, we see:

```r
function (.data, ..., .by_group = FALSE, .locale = NULL) 
{
    dots <- enquos(...)
    if (.by_group) {
        dots <- c(quos(!!!groups(.data)), dots)
    }
    loc <- arrange_rows(.data, dots = dots, locale = .locale)
    dplyr_row_slice(.data, loc)
}
```

The function doesn't actually sort anything; instead it calls the unexported function `arrange_rows` to do the sorting for it.

Looking into the code of `arrange_rows` (by typing `dplyr:::arrange_rows` into the console),  we see that this function itself delegates the actual sorting to *another* unexported function called `vec_order_radix`.

When we look at the code of *that* function, we see that it does not do the sorting itself either, instead calling a C function called `vctrs_order` to do the sorting via the `.Call` interface.

The `vctrs_order` function is defined [here](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/blob/8bbd8c4a69a9b3e2c42aa752c5339f949562af96/src/order.c#L183), and we can see from the code comments above it that it dispatches differently according to the type of vector passed. For short vectors (currently defined as less than 128 elements), it will use an insert sort, and for longer vectors it uses a radix sort (except for integer vectors, where it will use a count sort if there are between 128 and 10000 elements). You can follow the C code here to examine how it is done in detail if you choose.

But the bottom line is that there is no sorting done in R code at all - it is *usually* a radix sort implemented in C.